# Considerations and possible issues with Nested GIT repositories

Tags: git

I am thinking to have the following git repository setup for my project:

- Parent Folder – Includes a  local .git repository folder and will be push to

  - Child Folder 1: – Includes a  local .git repository folder and will be push to
  - Child Folder 2: – Includes a  local .git repository folder and will be push to

Above setup brings a few benefits for me, and I can have the parent project completely backed up in a separate repository while child folders (projects) can be stored in a less secure and shared github repositories.

Is there any problem with above setup? Is it supported? Is it going to cause issues down the road?

Comment: I do this all the time. Just make sure the child folders are `.gitignore`'d by the outer folder. You can also use `git submodule`, but that is its own mixed bag of pain, I don't recommend that path.

Answer (score 0):

> Is there any problem with above setup? Is it supported?

The problem is that your parent repo will only record gitlinks for each of your nested repos:

- it will record the name of the root folder and the SHA1 of a nested repo (that is a gitlink: name + SHA1),
- but will have no idea from *where* those nested repo are coming from.

If you clone again your parent repo later, you will get only empty folders for each of your sub-repos.

You should add those same nested repos as **[submodule](https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Git-Tools-Submodules)**.

The result is the same (nested git repos), but you have one more file in your parent repo: a `.gitmodules`. That file will record the remote url of the nested git repos, and will allow you to later clone your parent repo, and find back your nested git repos cloned properly, with the right content.